# Firefox JS not running unless debugged

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I have a simple piece of code, that works fine both in IE and Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox unless debugged.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" > </script>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#chb", function () {
        log("triggered, disabled = " + chb.disabled)
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#go", go);
    cnt = 0;
    function log(msg) {
        $("#log").append("<span>" + ++cnt + ". " + msg + "<br/></span>");
    }
    function go() {
        if (chb.disabled) {
            chb.disabled = null;
            console.log("set to null");
        }
        else {
            chb.disabled = true;
            console.log("set to true");
        }
        fireEvent(chb, "click");
    }
    function fireEvent(element, event) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        console.log("Event fired");
    }
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="chb">
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go">
<div id="log" />
</body>
</html>
```

It seems as if Firefox is unable to fire event. Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Comment: What have you done so far to debug the issue? Does the console show any errors?

Comment: The thing is, code works just fine if it's debugged. (it fires the fireEvent and adds <span>). But when you disable the debugger it simply won't work, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so if anyone stumbles across this problem... The thing is it's a bug. There is a problem, somewhere in Firefox, that you can't simulate an event just after you've madeyour input, button, or whatever enabled again. Simply use a function, (e.g. in this case it'd be like this:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#chb", logg);
     function logg () {
        log("triggered, disabled = " + chb.disabled)
    }
    /// some code here
    function go() {
        if (chb.disabled) {
            chb.disabled = null;
            console.log("set to null");
        }
        else {
            chb.disabled = true;
            console.log("set to true");
        }
        if(!chb.disabled)
             logg()

    }
```

Hopefully it helps